# cURL webpage through proxy; break loop

Tags: php, html, curl, php-curl

I have a page called proxyManager.php which allows a user to enter a proxy ip address and port; this is added to a database which is also accessed by another script called campaignManager.php.

campaignManager.php should keep trying to fetch a given page through a proxy from the database until it is successful in getting the right page. In my case this is when the page doesn't contain a certain string.

currently the system I use doesn't break out of the foreach proxy loop upon connection:

```
$query = "SELECT ipAddress, port FROM proxylist";
$res = $conn->query($query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
      while(!$proxyConnection){
        foreach ($res as $proxy)
        {
            $ip = $proxy['ipAddress'];
            $port = $proxy['port'];
            $sock = $ip .":". $port;
            $resultingPage = searchFunction($googleURL, $sock);
            if(isset($resultingPage)){
              if (!stringFlagged($resultingPage))
              {
                  echo "\n NOT BANNED PROXY";
                  $proxyConnection = true;

               }
               else {
                $proxyConnection = false;
                  echo "BANNED PROXY";
               }
```

This scripts aim is to fetch all proxies from the database, and foreach proxy, try and curl the page with the proxy settings. If stringFlagged it should try another proxy, if not, it should break from the foreach loop as the while loops conditions should have been met.

currently however it will keep trying all proxies, no matter if banned or not. I believe I need to use a break statement, however I am quite new to PHP and not sure how or where it would be needed.

Comment: As soon as you set the $proxyConnection to false, it should break the while loop. just place break after the $proxyConnection = false;

Comment: get rid of the while and just have the foreach, and use `break;` The problem is your while is checked _before_ starting the entire loop.

Comment: Thanks so much guys! helped me solve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Removing the while loop and adding a break when connected to the proxy will break out of the foreach loop as stated by @Scuzzy and @Hudson